# Meteor startup return function

Tags: meteor

I have seen quite a few times that the startup function of Meteor returns a function. What does it mean? Where is the function returned? Who is using the returned function？

```
Meteor.startup(function () {  
  Init();

  return Tracker.autorun(function () {
    const userId = Meteor.userId();  

    if (!userId) {
        //do something
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen startup returning a function, and I have never used it. It wont break and will work all the same, but I do not know why it is done in this example.

It is also strange that it is returning an autorun function... both startup and autorun are client api event handler hooks ... no one should be listening to the results of the function calls becuase these calls are not made by the app but rather the meteor platform, their function is to run code at either startup, or as a separate reactive fiber (autorun).